# ClassCastException With Model Extending ActiveJDBC Model

Tags: java, activejdbc

I have a class A that extends the activejdbc.Model class in a common library used in multiple of my projects.

I want to add methods to that class in a project using that library without having to go modify the library (the methods will only be used for this project).

What I did: I created a class B extending class A and added my desired methods.

The problem: When I run JDBC methods such as `B.where("foo = ?", bar)`, I get a `List<A>` object instead of `List<B>` which causes ClassCastException in following code.

I tried to run the ActiveJDBC instrumentation in the second project (the one with class B) but it tells me I do not have any ActiveJDBC model.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Can you please create a simple project that replicates this behavior and push it to Github? it will be easier to help you

Comment: This is a repo I put in place to demonstrate the issue.
https://github.com/PaulSzyller/example-activejdbc-extend

In the real project, the common directory would actually be a github submodule.